# Generation of documentation for QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, documentation

I've written rather much docstrings etc. in my QGIS plugin, mostly in order to keep track of the functions for myself, but it would be nice to have some more documentation, like a sphinx page.

I have never generated any documentation previously but I know that `pb_tool` runs `sphinx` when I deploy the plugin. But the `index.html` in help\build\html folder is rather empty.

Any suggestions of which settings to update etc.?

Comment: Is this question actually specific to QGIS / GIS? If it's more of a coding question, you might want to try it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead. Just a suggestion, I'm not familiar enough with writing QGIS plugins to know for sure.